# Javascript Convert Date from short format to Long format

Tags: javascript, date

I am using the following code:

```
var date="May-02-2012";
var startDate = date; 
var tmp = startDate.split('-'); 
tmp.splice(1, 0, ','); 
var convertedStartDate = new Date(tmp.join(' ')); 
var month = convertedStartDate.getMonth() + 1 
var day = convertedStartDate.getDate(); 
var year = convertedStartDate.getFullYear(); 
var shortStartDate = ('0' + day).slice(-2) + "-" + ('0' + month).slice(-2) + "-" + ('0' + year).slice(-2); 
return(shortStartDate);
```

The code above allows my to convert May-02-2012 to 02-05-12

however, I now need to convert it from 02-05-12 back to May-02-2012

But I can't work it out..

Comment: Check out date.js on the Google code site: http://code.google.com/p/datejs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No too hard provided the format is as you specified. The following doesn't do any testing so if the format is wrong, it might to awry. But so will any function if you give it the wrong format.

```
var s = '02-05-12';

function toWeirdDate(s) {
   var months = 'Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec'.split(' ');
   var bits = s.split('-');
   return months[--bits[1]] + '-' + bits[0] + '-20' + bits[2];
}

alert(toWeirdDate(s)); // May-02-2012
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a library I found this one to work quite well: http://www.datejs.com/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [javascript date format](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format).